# Difference between Tweepy Streaming and Tweepy search

Tags: api, twitter, streaming, tweepy

What is the difference between Tweepy Streaming and Restful `APIs`, I know one of the difference is you can get bulk of the data with `Streaming APIs` 
And also what is the meaning of realtime data with `Streaming APIs`, if I want to extract all the information for **#Messi**, which will be right option, streaming or search? All help is appreciated

Answer (score 3):

Twitter’s Search API gives you access to a data set that already exists from tweets that have occurred. Through the Search API users request tweets that match some sort of “search” criteria. You can think that,  user would do a search directly at Twitter (navigating to search.twitter.com and entering in keywords). Also for an individual user, the maximum number of tweets you can receive is the last 3,200 tweets, regardless of the query criteria. With a specific keyword, you can typically only poll the last 5,000 tweets per keyword.

Unlike Twitter’s Search API where you are polling data from tweets that have already happened, Twitter’s Streaming API is a push of data as tweets happen in near real-time. Twitter that whenever they receive tweets that match keywords relating to “messi”, they will deliver the tweet directly to you as they happen.

In breaf, Streaming is push of data by Twitter, Search is pull of data initiated by the end user.

You can get more information [here](https://brightplanet.com/2013/06/twitter-firehose-vs-twitter-api-whats-the-difference-and-why-should-you-care/)